# How to write a JNI dll bridge

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, jna

i have a dll driver to use in my Java application.
I read that i need to create a dll bridge for JNI. First of all I would like to know if exists some utility to creare automatically this bridge.

I have the source code of the Dll, and I also know how to creare my bridge header file (javah) but I can not understand how to put into bridge implementation because i just need to call the driver method....
Can you help me?

For example this is the header of my driver:

```
BOOL CALLINGCONV IsInitialized();
int  CALLINGCONV Initialize(int Slot);
int  CALLINGCONV Finalize();
int  CALLINGCONV FinalizeML(int nSlot);
```

I also read about JNA, it seems easier but maybe it not very fast, is it true?
Thnak you

Comment: I forgot to say that this is a C driver.

Comment: How fast do you need it to be? How often are these methods called?

Comment: JNA (https://github.com/twall/jna#readme) might be easier than JNI for this use case.

Comment: I have to call few methods (2-3) per seconds and all methods has <200KB byte params.

Comment: 200kB parameters? What kind of data are we passing?

Comment: Yep this is a signature application, i have to sign some logs with a smartcard.

Comment: You can probably get a JNA example up and running before you even get a JNI stub code compiled, and it'll be substantially easier to debug.  Using primitive arguments and direct mapping, performance won't be much different from writing directly to JNI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) is as easy as JNA, but as fast as raw JNI. For example, this Java class could let access efficiently those four functions in Java, assuming the header and library files are named "Driver.h" and "Driver.lib" respectively:

```
import com.googlecode.javacpp.*;
import com.googlecode.javacpp.annotation.*;

@Platform(include="Driver.h",link="Driver")
public class Driver {
    static { Loader.load(); }
    public static native @Cast("BOOL") boolean IsInitialized();
    public static native int Initialize(int Slot);
    public static native int Finalize();
    public static native int FinalizeML(int nSlot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you 2 different libraries that make easier work with JNI

- [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html)
- [JACE](http://code.google.com/p/jace/)